# implementation of sink connector in java package

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i had started zookeeper ,kafka server ,kafka producer and kafka consumer and i had put jdbc sql connector jar downloaded from confluent and put the jar in the path and i have mentioned plugin.path in connect-standalone properties.and i have run connect-standalone.bat ....\config\connect-standalone.properties ....\config\sink-quickstart-mysql.properties without any error  but it has many warnings and it is not getting started,but my data is not getting reflected in tables.what i have missed?can u please help me out i have below warnings

```
                                                                                                    org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name io.netty.inter
nal.tcnative.SSLPrivateKeyMethod
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:312)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:382)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$Inte
rnalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:433)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scan
PluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:325)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scan
UrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:261)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.init
PluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:209)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.init
Loaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:202)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.jav
a:60)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone
.java:79)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLPriva
teKeyMethod
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:310)
        ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to write a source connector yourself unless you need to connect kafka to some exotic data source. Popular tools like mysql are already quite well covered. There is already a "jdbc-connector" by confluent that does what you want.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/index.html

You'll need a working kafka-connect installation and then you can "connect" your mysql tables to kafka with an HTTP POST to the kafka connect API. Just specify a comma-separate list of the tables you'd like to be used as sources in the `tables.whitelist` attribute. For example, something like this....

```
curl -X POST $KAFKA_CONNECT_API/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
      "name": "jdbc_source_mysql_01",
      "config": {
              "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
              "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/test",
              "connection.user": "connect_user",
              "connection.password": "connect_password",
              "topic.prefix": "mysql-01-",
              "poll.interval.ms" : 3600000,
              "table.whitelist" : "test.accounts",
              "mode":"bulk"
              }
      }'
```

Comment: Here in this link ,kafka connect is given for mac and linux.can you tell how to implement for windows

Comment: @user14 Kafka Connect is a Java process, it's not specific to an OS. The startup scripts exist in the bin/windows folder

Comment: @OneCricketeer i have downloaded confluentzip file for my windows https://nijanthanravi.wordpress.com/2019/07/14/setup-confluent-kafka-on-windows/ while installing zookeeper i am facing "C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_261" is not recognized as a internal or external command" how to fix this?

Comment: @user14 Your Java installation is messed up. Try reinstalling the latest Java 8

Comment: @OneCricketeer i had started zookeeper ,kafka server ,kafka producer and kafka consumer and i had put jdbc sql connector jar downloaded from confluent and put the jar in the path and i  have mentioned plugin.path  in connect-standalone properties.and i have run connect-standalone.bat ..\..\config\connect-standalone.properties  ..\..\config\sink-quickstart-mysql.properties
without any error ,but my data is not getting reflected in tables.what i have missed?can u please hep me out

Comment: my kafka connect end up with   warning but not with success message                                                                       
WARNING: A provider org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.LoggingResou
rce registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces appl
icable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provi
der org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.LoggingResource will be igno
red.
Dec 12, 2020 12:45:40 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers checkPro
viderRuntime

Comment: @user14 Please edit your initial post or create new post for new issues

Comment: please check the above content @OneCricketeer